# How to use PHP sessions to get a login system to work?

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I am needing help with a somewhat simple task but I want to tackle this task so that it works on all browsers. My only problem is that I only have access to a Mac and no PC machines. So here is what I am needing to do:

I have a user area where people take quizzes. Some quizzes are longer than others and what is happening is that of a user completes the quiz quickly, the quiz is submitted and scored. However, if the user takes longer than 30 minutes to an hour for example, the quiz will not submit and it will kick the user back to my home page.

I am using PHP and SESSIONS for the users login data. I do not have any expiration date on my SESSIONS and I do not know why it is doing this. Do I need to switch to cookies? Or Can I add something to the SESSIONS to make so the user will NEVER be logged out until the click on the "Logout" link.

Comment: session time-out id default is 30min, but you can increase it to what ever you need.ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "18000");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it on php.ini file, defining a global timeout for sessions.

But, during application runtime, you can define it as a ini_set variable.

Here, you can set a timeout of 90 minutes after last server request.

```
ini_set('session.cache_expire',90);
```

More about session ini, you can find here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

You can extend this time ever request. I don't know about disable session expiration.

But, as alternative, you can enable some polling on server to signalize an user interaction. i.e., some examples are found here: [jQuery - polling of a job queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186626/jquery-polling-of-a-job-queue) and here http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/posts/jquery-periodicalupdater-ajax-polling/

[]'s,

And Past

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thorough explanation: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)